# Copy vertices across a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm very new to 3D modeling and StackExchange. Forgive me if I make any missteps.

I'd like to take these edge loops, extrusions, and vertices and copy them along the mesh, without creating a new mesh or screwing up my topology. I know that I could repeat the operation by hand, but is there an automated way to perform this copy/paste scenario quickly and accurately?

I've tried searching, but I can't find anything quite what I expected. My vocabulary for 3D Modeling is still very limited.

Thanks for any guidance you can offer.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your mesh, you probably could have gotten away with using the array modifier to clone each cylinder across. This would save you time as you only would need to edit the first one, and all the others would inherit your changes.